# Complex Gaussian Integrals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, numerical-methods

Starting from the relation ,
$\begin{equation}
 \int dz  d\overline{z} e^{-|z|^{2}} \; \overline{z}^{n} z^{m} = \pi n!\; \delta_{mn}. 
\end{equation}$

what is the value of this integral when we make the shift from $z$ to $z-a$ where $a$ is complex number in general?

Comment: I guess you are integrating over all of $\mathbb C$ and "$dz\,d\overline{z}$" is area .  But tell us more about the "shift" you intend.

Comment: @GEdgar yes, I am integrating over all $\mathbb{C}$ and the shift is simply a complex number without any variable inside. I guess the answer would be the same? what do you think?

Comment: If the shift you mean is $$\int_{\mathbb{C}} dz  d\overline{z} e^{-|z-a|^{2}} \; \overline{(z-a)}^{n} (z-a)^{m}$$then yes, the two are the same.  But it was not clear to me what shift you intended.

Comment: Thanks GEdagr for your comment !